# Windows Server Backup: compress output .vhd

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

I would like to have the Windows Server Backup data compressed on the file system. The lion's share of data is consumed by `.vhd` files in the `\WindowsImageBackup\<hostname>\Backup <timestamp>\` directory.

I have tried pre-enabling compression for the entire volume, but Windows Server backup seems to explicitly disable the `compression` flag for the `.vhd` files it is producing. I also have tried setting the `compression` flag for the `.vhd`s after the backup is done, but it seems to be reset upon the next backup run.

So how would I force the software to just stick with the compression choice I have selected? Is there any good reason for Windows Server Backup to disable compression for the `.vhd` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I have at least found the answer for question #2 - ***the "good reason" to disable compression on .vhd files is because it is broken beyond repair for common NTFS volumes:***

A [blog post on VHDs and Hyper-V](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ranjanajain/archive/2010/03/23/virtual-hard-disk-vhd-architecture-explained.aspx) states

> VHDs cannot be mounted within a compressed folder in Windows Server 2008 R2. This was possible in Hyper-V role in Windows Server 2008, but this capability was explicitly blocked in the Hyper-V role in Windows Server 2008 R2 since the compressed file size limit is relatively small. A dynamically expandable VHD can easily outgrow that limit and get corrupted.

while [the MSDN library](http://blogs.technet.com/b/seanearp/archive/2011/07/06/file-system-limitation.aspx) explicitly mentions it as a file system limitation:

> If you compress a file that is larger than 30 gigabytes, the compression may not succeed.

and [KB967351 (*A heavily fragmented file in an NTFS volume may not grow beyond a certain size*)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967351/en-us) states that

> When a file is very fragmented, NTFS uses more space to save the
>   description of the allocations that is associated with the fragments.
>   The allocation information is stored in one or more file records. When
>   the allocation information is stored in multiple file records, another
>   structure, known as the ATTRIBUTE_LIST, stores information about those
>   file records. The number of ATTRIBUTE_LIST_ENTRY structures that the
>   file can have is limited.
>
> We cannot give an exact file size limit for a compressed or a highly
>   fragmented file. An estimate would depend on using certain average
>   sizes to describe the structures. These, in turn, determine how many
>   structures fit in other structures. If the level of fragmentation is
>   high, the limit is reached earlier. When this limit is reached, you
>   receive the following error message:
>
> [...]
>   STATUS_FILE_SYSTEM_LIMITATION The requested operation could not be
>   completed due to a file system limitation[...]
>
> Compressed files are more likely to reach the limit because of the way
>   the files are stored on disk. Compressed files require more extents to
>   describe their layout. Also, decompressing and compressing a file
>   increases fragmentation significantly. The limit can be reached when
>   write operations occur to an already compressed chunk location. The
>   limit can also be reached by a sparse file. This size limit is usually
>   between 40 gigabytes (GB) and 90 GB for a very fragmented file.

The hotfix accompanying KB967351 is meant to add support for something it is calling "large File Record Segment (FRS)". Format.exe is getting a new parameter `/L` to enable this for a newly created file system. Format.exe included in Server 2012 already has `/L`, just as the [`Format-Volume` cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848665.aspx) has the `-UseLargeFRS` parameter. I wonder if Server Backup in 2012 allows for compressed VHDs by default.